# pass argument to link and update table

Tags: php

I am not that good in php so you migt find it simple.

this php is not updating on the database

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//credentials...

$id= intval($_GET['id']);
$likes= intval($_GET['likes']);

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db) or die(mysqli_error());


    $sql1="UPDATE OBJECTS SET LIKES='$likes' WHERE ID='$id'";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);


?>
```

I tried to run the link `http://justedhak.com/old-files/singleactivity.php/id=1&likes=1` by passing the arguments but nothing happen.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Are the values of $id and $likes being set? Have you var_dumped the query to see if there are any issues with it?

Comment: @RemanBroder I tried to pass the argument in the link as mentioend in the question , I ran the query manualy in the database and it was good , how can i debug it? I am using the php on godaddy through web browser

Comment: What error are you getting? Are LIKES and ID capitalized on your table and are those fields set to take strings?

Comment: @MartavisGriffin I guess thats my problem the fields are int not string it seems I passing the value string ..right ? and yes I run the query as it is and it worked, I edit in php like this `$sql1="UPDATE OBJECTS SET LIKES=$likes WHERE ID=$id";` and still not working

Comment: Mysql is case sensitive, is the table name and fields all capitalized? You really should be getting an error from this if they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url has an error. The GET variables are delimited by a ? after the page address.

http://justedhak.com/old-files/singleactivity.php/id=1&likes=1

http://justedhak.com/old-files/singleactivity.php?id=1&likes=1

Change / to ?